# Jenkins version 2.375.3. failed to start after "yum upgrade -y"

Tags: jenkins

Here is the exceptions:

```
`
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class hudson.slaves.NodeProperty (java.lang.Integer is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; hudson.slaves.NodeProperty is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @76908cc0)
    at hudson.model.Node.getNodeProperty(Node.java:496)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.matrixauth.AmbiguityMonitor$NodeContributor.record(AmbiguityMonitor.java:135)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.matrixauth.AmbiguityMonitor.recordAgents(AmbiguityMonitor.java:269)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:109)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:115)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:185)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1161)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:70)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:290)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:49)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1196)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:986)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:264)`
```

I've done a "yum upgrade -y' and os is updated from 8.4 Linux 8.7. All other servers in the os came up ok except Jenkins server (version 2.375.3).

Static hostname: example.com
Icon name: computer-vm
Chassis: vm
Machine ID: bfc97d8b8a334465bcd1e6fed83a814f
Boot ID: 1b9527c52ef04f0f8380d37305a9a4fa
Virtualization: kvm
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.7 (Ootpa)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos
Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-425.13.1.el8_7.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64

Answer (score 0):

After I revert back Jenkins to previous version and it came up ok, still don't know the 2.375.3 verion faile.

yum install jenkins-2.346.3